# phonegap build / apple reject because of support for audio in the UIBackgroundModes key

Tags: cordova, location, phonegap

I am using a geolocation plugin and my app is rejected on the apple store

I am using phonegap build to compile

Your app declares support for audio in the UIBackgroundModes key in your Info.plist but did not include features that require persistent audio.

I have added

```
<config-file platform="ios" target="*-Info.plist" parent="UIBackgroundModes">
        <array>
            <string>location</string>
        </array>
    </config-file>
```

and removed it but the rejection is still the same !

My plugins are

```
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy" source="npm"/>
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" source="npm"/>


   <feature name="Geolocation">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVLocation" />
    </feature>
```

Comment: I reckon if you are not playing any background audio then removed it from plist. I was playing in my case, they asked me for a video as a proof and accept it later.

Comment: Try unpacking your ipa and verify that UIBackgroundModes is set. Something is adding it -- neither of those plugins add it according to their source, and by default phonegap does not add it. Also do you have hydration enabled on PhoneGap Build? If so make sure to disable it.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, 
- no I don't have hydration enabled
- when I unzip the ipa and check the Info.plist there is no UIBackgroundModes 

: (